# Is there a GeoDjango tutorial for GeoRSSFeeds?

Tags: python, open-source-gis, geodjango

I'm going through GeoDjango basics right now. Ideally, I'd like to publish a GeoRSS from a set of data I have that is already in Django's database. I know how to get a regular Feed working, but when I try GeoRSSFeed, I'm running into problems.  One of my main problems is:

```
Exception Value: __init__() takes at least 4 arguments (1 given)
```

In reference to my urls.py file when I try to make my Feed to GeoRSSFeed. Is there no tutorial for getting GeoRSSFeeds to work? I've seen [this](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/feeds/) but it really isn't helping me.

Comment: Can you provide more detail? What's in the relevant part of your `urls.py`? Have you subclassed the feed to let it know you have a GeoRSS feed?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/gUfZR9sj

and 

https://github.com/frewsxcv/DjangoCAD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the code it appears that the django.contrib.gis.feeds depends on a deprecated version of the Django syndication framework.

Reported as https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17782

It's possible to work around the issue as the Geodjango feed generators still seem to work. Here's an example:

```
from django.contrib.syndication.views import Feed
from django.contrib.gis.feeds import GeoRSSFeed

class MyGeoFeed(Feed):
    """ Example feed working around https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17782
    Note that the geoetry and item_geometry must be instance methods and not
    class attributes.
    """
    feed_type = GeoRSSFeed

    def feed_extra_kwargs(self, obj):
        return {'geometry' : self.geometry(obj)}

    def item_extra_kwargs(self, item):
        return {'geometry' : self.item_geometry(item)}

    def geometry(self, obj):
        # Return geos object as per geodjango docs

    def item_geometry(self, item):
        # Return geos object as per geodjango docs

    # Other feed methods as per django syndication docs.
```